# Query return the highest number for each row

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Can I get  highest  totalColumns number grouped by section_mod_id

Query

```
SELECT 
    day_id, section_mod_id, count(day_id) as totalColumns 
FROM 
    `supervision` sup
INNER JOIN   
    `section_mod` s ON sup.section = s.section_mod_id
GROUP BY 
    day_id, section_mod_id 
ORDER BY 
    (s.section_mod_id) ASC
```

For example

```
day_id  section_mod_id totalColumns
-----------------------------------
127          2             3
103          2             1
23           2             2
105          2             1
23           6             1
```

to this

```
day_id  section_mod_id totalColumns
-----------------------------------
127          2             3 
23           6             1
```

only return the highest number for each section

is it possible  using mysql  database?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below using subquery.

Note : you can use temporary table for the inner subquery.

```
    select day_id,section_mod_id,totalColumns from 
    (
    select t1.day_id ,t1.section_mod_id,t1.totalColumns
    ,count(*) as rowNumber 
    from        
         (SELECT  day_id, section_mod_id, count(day_id) as totalColumns FROM supervision sup
           INNER JOIN section_mod s ON sup.section = s.section_mod_id  GROUP BY day_id, section_mod_id 
         ) t1
          inner join 
         (SELECT  day_id, section_mod_id, count(day_id) as totalColumns FROM supervision sup
           INNER JOIN section_mod s ON sup.section = s.section_mod_id  GROUP BY day_id, section_mod_id 
         )t2 
       on t1.section_mod_id=t2.section_mod_id
       and t1.totalColumns<=t2.totalColumns
    group by t1.day_id, t1.section_mod_id,t1.totalColumns
    ) t where rowNumber=1
```

Answer (score 1):

In most databases you can use the ANSI standard `row_number()` function:

```
SELECT sm.*
FROM (SELECT day_id, section_mod_id, count(*) as totalColumns,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY section_mod_id ORDER BY count(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM supervision s INNER JOIN
           section_mod m ON s.section = m.section_mod_id
      GROUP BY day_id, section_mod_id 
     ) sm
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

In MySQL, the simplest method is probably this trick:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(day_id ORDER BY totalColumns DESC), ',', 1) as day_id,
       section_mod_id, MAX(totalColumns)
FROM (SELECT day_id, section_mod_id, count(*) as totalColumns
      FROM supervision s INNER JOIN
           section_mod m ON s.section = m.section_mod_id
      GROUP BY day_id, section_mod_id 
     ) sm
WHERE seqnum = 1
GROUP BY section_mod_id
```

Comment: I tried mysql solution, but I'm getting this error " Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'"

Comment: First query errors "An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 18)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 18)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "SELECT" at position 19)
An alias was previously found. (near "seqnum" at position 164)
Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 312)
An alias was previously found. (near "sm" at position 314)

Comment: Second one An alias was previously found. (near "section_mod_id" at position 98)
An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 138)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 138)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "SELECT" at position 139)
Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 336)
An alias was previously found. (near "sm" at position 338)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "GROUP BY" at position 360)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "GROUP BY" at position 360)

Comment: The error was because of seqnum   not defined  any way I removed it and the code worked thank you